# How to connect the ASP.NET web application to a SQL Server located in different domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server located in different domain. I am able to connect to the SQL Server using the command

```
runas /noprofile /netonly /user:domain\username ssms.exe
```

Now, I want to access this server in my web application. How to do it?

How to write connection string for this case?

Someone told me that this can be achieved by changing some in `machine.config` file, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

If the application server and the SQL server are on different domains, you will need to use SQL Server Authentication to connect.

First, make sure SQL Authentication is enabled on your server:

1. Right-click on the server's node in the Object Explorer of SSMS
2. Pick Properties to open the Server Properties dialog
3. Under the Security tab, verify "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" is checked.
4. Restart the SQL Server service if you have made any changes.

then, expand the Security node under your server in SSMS.  Right-click on Logins, and select "New Login...".  Select "SQL Server Authentication" and choose a username and password.  Set your User Mapping appropriately.

At this stage, it is a good idea to try testing the connection to your server through SSMS using the user you just created.  If it fails, make sure you restarted your SQL Server service in step 4 above.

Afterwards, your connection string will look similar, except replace `Integrated Security=true;` with `Integrated Security=false;user=[username];password=[password]`

Comment: i do not have permission to create a login, besides the login credential i have, is already mapped to SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" i tried connection string with user name and password but it did not work.. anything to be done with impersonation or something?

Comment: There are two issues at play here: your login needs to be set as SQL Server Authentication -- NOT Windows Authentication, and your server needs to be set as allowing both Windows and SQL Server Authentication.

Are you sure your existing credential is using SQL Server authentication?  The login itself cannot be using both.  You're using `runas` to connect with SSMS, which uses Windows authentication, so I would imagine that you do not have a SQL Server Authentication login.